# XML parsing for repeating list

Tags: xml, shell

I have an input file.xml with repeating list enclosed between  like below.I have to extract the fields from each repeating data and append in a new file with the format mentioned in desired output

```
<File>
<Class attr1="name1" attr2="sub1">
</Class>
</File>
<File>
<Class attr1="name2" attr2="sub2">
</Class>
</File>
<File>
<Class attr1="name3" attr2="sub3">
</Class>
</File>
```

desired output like below in a new file

```
"name1","sub1"
"name2","sub2"
"name3","sub3"
```

I tried using xmlint but it is only extracting the first occurence of the repeating list("name1","sub1").Please help me .

Comment: this is invalid XML. an XML file must have **only one** root element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix your XML by requiring a root node:

```
$ cat file.xml
<root>
    <File>
    <Class attr1="name1" attr2="sub1">
    </Class>
    </File>
    <File>
    <Class attr1="name2" attr2="sub2">
    </Class>
    </File>
    <File>
    <Class attr1="name3" attr2="sub3">
    </Class>
    </File>
</root>
```

you can use your preferred XML tool. I like [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//File/Class' \
    -o '"' -v './@attr1' -o '","' -v './@attr2' -o '"' -n \
    file.xml
"name1","sub1"
"name2","sub2"
"name3","sub3"
```

The documentation for xmlstarlet is... lacking. The `-m` option for a `select` template is basically a loop: match the xpath and process the following options for each match

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file contains valid XML and using `xmllint` and `sed`

```
xmllint --xpath '//Class/@*' test.xml | sed -re 's/(attr1=([^= ]+) attr2=([^= ]+)){1}/\2,\3\n/g'
```

Result:

```
"name1","sub1"
"name2","sub2"
"name3","sub3"
```